# Prepared Statements with functions syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to run this:

```
mysql> prepare stmt1 from "UPDATE test.users SET password = password('?') WHERE usrid = ?";
mysql> prepare stmt1 from "UPDATE test.users SET password = password(?) WHERE usrid = ?";
```

How can I make a prepared statement where a function takes my variable as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some double quotes around your prepared statement:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt_name FROM "SELECT name FROM Country WHERE code = ?";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> SET @test_parm = "FIN";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXECUTE stmt_name USING @test_parm;
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| Finland |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, you caught the syntax error, but my real question was about incorporating functions into the statement. Thanks.

Comment: Well, did you just try to call it?

Comment: It turned out to be all about the double quotes. I had a brain fart. Thanks, Pascal for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the gross syntax error (missing quotes around the prepared string) is fixed, the question resolves to "how to get an argument into a function in a prepared statement", I believe.

The first example passes the password string '?' to the password function - it probably is *not* what you had in mind.  The second example passes the first value given to the statement when it is executed to the password function, and the second value is used to identify the relevant `usrid`.

This assumes a standard interpretation of SQL - I know of no reason to think it won't apply to MySQL too.